# MySql copying a small amount of data from each table on one server to another

Tags: mysql, copy

I have a new database set up that is very similar to another database that is full of data. I was wondering if there is a way to copy say 10 records from every table over to the new database. I am working on creating some web reports and would like some "dummy" data to see how things are working. I have seen some methods of exporting data from certain tables and importing them to the new database, but I have about 50 tables to copy and that would be very time consuming. Is there a, hopefully easy :), way of accomplishing this? Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: How big is the db you are copying from? Is it possible to recreate the original db?

Comment: Create a linked server. Write a procedure to fetch a list of tables, their schemas, and `INSERT ... SELECT ... LIMIT 10`

Comment: The database is pretty large, about 20 gigs. @njk how would I create a linked server?

Answer (score 0):

From your terminal you could use `mysqldump` to export data from selected tables:

```
mysqldump -u<username> -p<password> <database> <tabel1> <table2> <table3> > dump.sql
```

Then to import them into your other database:

```
mysql -u<username> -p<password> <database> < dump.sql
```